# How to redraw a subviews in landscape

Tags: swift, swift5

Good afternoon Community,

I am trying to add two subviews to a viewcontroller by means of an extension, but when rotating the device it does not respect the layout, any option on how to make it look correct?

I attach my code below and a couple of example photos, the first photo is how I would like it to look, and the rest of the ui is lost.

[image: this is the first one]
[image: The error in landscape]
[image: The error when I rotate the device to portrait again]

This is my code:

```
  func presentCustomAlertController(on ViewController:UIViewController,toPresentCustomView customView:UIView,withBackgroundView backGroundView:UIView){
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    guard let targetView = ViewController.view  else {return}
   
    backGroundView.alpha = 0
    backGroundView.backgroundColor = .black
    backGroundView.frame = targetView.bounds
    targetView.addSubview(backGroundView)
    targetView.addSubview(customView)
    
    customView.setNeedsLayout()
    customView.setNeedsDisplay()
    customView.layoutIfNeeded()
    customView.layoutSubviews()
    
    targetView.setNeedsLayout()
    targetView.setNeedsDisplay()
    targetView.layoutIfNeeded()
    targetView.layoutSubviews()
    
    backGroundView.setNeedsDisplay()
    backGroundView.setNeedsLayout()
    backGroundView.layoutIfNeeded()
    
 
    
    customView.frame = CGRect(x: targetView.center.x, y: targetView.center.y, width: targetView.frame.size.width-80, height: 300)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        backGroundView.alpha = 0.6
        
    },completion: { done in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            customView.center = targetView.center
           
        })
        
    })
    
}
```

}

Comment: Just FYI: The line `customView.center = targetView.center` does not do what you probably think it does. In particular it does _not_ center `customView` within `targetView`.

Comment: @matt what do you recommend to me to center that view without the property  center?

Comment: Don't know because you are not showing enough info. You are saying `customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` which suggests you have autolayout constraints. But you have not shown what they are, and in any case, this will cause setting the `center` to break, because `center`/`frame` and autolayout are opposites. You can't use both; they will fight each other.

Comment: Also just in general this is _not_ how you really present a custom view controller as a centered alert.